# How dangerous is forkProcess? How can I use it safely?

Tags: haskell, fork, ghc

I’d like to play tricks with [`forkProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess), where I want to clone my Haskell process, and then let both clones talk to each other (maybe using Cloud Haskell to send even closures around).

But I wonder how well that works with the GHC runtime. Does anyone have experience here?

The documenation for `forkProcess` says that no other threads are copied, so I assume all data used by other threads will then be garbage collected in the fork, which sounds good. But that means that finalizers will run in both clone, which may or may not be the right thing to do…

I assume I can’t just use it without worry; but are there rules I can follow that will make sure its use is safe?

Comment: There are probably the same problems as with the posix `fork` itself in C: https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them -- anything non-trivial in the child has a tendency to blow up (including I/O and memory allocations), the only real use-case is to prepare the environment and exec some other binary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But that means that finalizers will run in both clone, which may or may not be the right thing to do…

[Finalizers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-Mem-Weak.html#v:addFinalizer) are very rarely used in Haskell, and even where they are used, I would expect them to only have in-process effects. For example, a finalizer calls `hClose` on garbage-collected Handles if you forgot to do it yourself. This is easy to demonstrate: the following program fails with `openFile: resource exhausted (Too many open files)`, but if you uncomment the `pure ()`, the Handles get garbage-collected and the program completes successfully.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Mem

main :: IO ()
main = do
  rs <- replicateM 1000 $ do
    threadDelay 1000  -- not sure why did is needed; maybe to give control back
                      -- to the OS, so it can recycle the file descriptors?
    performGC
    openFile "input" ReadMode
    --pure ()
  print rs  -- force all the Handles to still be alive by this point
```

File descriptors are process-owned and are copied by `forkProcess`, so it makes sense to have each clone close their copies.

The case which would be problematic is if a finalizer was cleaning up a system-owned resource, e.g. deleting a file. But I hope no library is relying on finalizers to delete such resources, because [as the documentation explains](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-Mem-Weak.html#g:5), finalizers are not guaranteed to run. So it's better to use something like `bracket` to cleanup resources (although the cleanup is still not guaranteed, [e.g. if `bracket` is used from a thread](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-07-30-bracket)).

What the documentation for `forkProcess` is warning about is not finalizers, but the fact that other threads will appear to end abruptly inside the forked process. This is especially problematic if those threads are holding locks. Normally, two threads can use `modifyMVar_` to ensure that only one thread at a time is running a critical section, and as long as each thread is only holding the lock for a finite amount of time, the other thread can simply wait for the `MVar` to become available. If you call `forkProcess` while one thread is in the middle of a `modifyMVar_`, however, that thread will not continue in the cloned process, and so the cloned process cannot simply call `modifyMVar_` or it could get stuck forever while waiting for a non-existing thread to release the lock. Here is a program demonstrating the problem.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.Posix.Process

-- >>> main
-- (69216,"forkIO thread",0)
-- (69216,"main thread",1)
-- (69216,"forkIO thread",2)
-- (69216,"main thread",3)
-- (69216,"forkIO thread",4)
-- (69216,"main thread",5)
-- calling forkProcess
-- forkProcess main thread waiting for MVar...
-- (69216,"forkIO thread",6)
-- (69216,"original main thread",7)
-- (69216,"forkIO thread",8)
-- (69216,"original main thread",9)
-- (69216,"forkIO thread",10)
-- (69216,"original main thread",11)
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mvar <- newMVar (0 :: Int)
  _ <- forkIO $ replicateM_ 6 $ do
    modifyMVar_ mvar $ \i -> do
      threadDelay 100000
      processID <- getProcessID
      print (processID, "forkIO thread", i)
      pure (i+1)
  threadDelay 50000
  replicateM_ 3 $ do
    modifyMVar_ mvar $ \i -> do
      threadDelay 100000
      processID <- getProcessID
      print (processID, "main thread", i)
      pure (i+1)
  putStrLn "calling forkProcess"
  _ <- forkProcess $ do
    threadDelay 25000
    replicateM_ 3 $ do
      putStrLn "forkProcess main thread waiting for MVar..."
      modifyMVar_ mvar $ \i -> do
        threadDelay 100000
        processID <- getProcessID
        print (processID, "forkProcess main thread", i)
        pure (i+1)
  replicateM_ 3 $ do
    modifyMVar_ mvar $ \i -> do
      threadDelay 100000
      processID <- getProcessID
      print (processID, "original main thread", i)
      pure (i+1)
  threadDelay 100000
```

As the output shows, the forkProcess main thread gets stuck waiting forever for the MVar, and never prints the `forkProcess main thread` line. If you move the `threadDelay`s outside the `modifyMVar_` critical section, the forkIO thread is a lot less likely to be in the middle of that critical section when `forkProcess` is called, so you'll see an output which looks like this instead:

```
(69369,"forkIO thread",0)
(69369,"main thread",1)
(69369,"forkIO thread",2)
(69369,"main thread",3)
(69369,"forkIO thread",4)
(69369,"main thread",5)
calling forkProcess
(69369,"forkIO thread",6)
(69369,"original main thread",7)
forkProcess main thread waiting for MVar...
(69370,"forkProcess main thread",6)
(69369,"forkIO thread",8)
(69369,"original main thread",9)
forkProcess main thread waiting for MVar...
(69370,"forkProcess main thread",7)
(69369,"forkIO thread",10)
(69369,"original main thread",11)
forkProcess main thread waiting for MVar...
(69370,"forkProcess main thread",8)
```

After the `forkProcess` call, there are now two MVars which both hold the value 5, and so in the original process, `original main thread` and `forkIO thread` are both incrementing one MVar, while in the other process `forkProcess main thread` is incrementing the other.